# Flask installation on windows vs Ubuntu

Tags: python, flask

I have cloned the git repository of flask(https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask). I run Python 3.4.1 on both my windows and ubuntu machines. To install flask(on windows), I just change directory to flask repository on my machine and run `python setup.py build install` . Flask successfully installs and runs. When I try repeating the same steps on ubuntu, it simply throws an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flask_example.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

I tried installing flask through pip, `pip install flask` and by using "virtualenv" with easy_install as well. I still get the same error. Can anyone tell me what the issue could be?

Comment: in ubuntu i have python 2.7 and python 3.4.1 both... but my current alias for python is 3.4.1 @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Ok answered properly :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all Ubuntu versions so far, `pip` command defaults to one that installs packages for the latest Python 2 version installed, i.e. most probably Python 2.7; this is the python that will start with `python` command.

Python 3 instead is runnable as `python3` or `python3.4`; there is a corresponding version of pip, such as `pip3` (for the default Python 3 version), or `pip3.4` for the pip that specifically installs the packages for the Python 3.4 versions.

Most notably, pip does not know anything about what are the possible aliases in the command shell (`bash`, `zsh`), and thus is completely oblivious to those.